# Using Google Sheets script to check a cache sheet for each key

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am pulling stock market data from Yahoo! Finance. For data that does not change often, I do not want to contact Yahoo! each time, but source data from a `db` sheet that acts as a cache:

1. `yahoofinance()` is called per ticker from 'Dashboard' sheet
2. `yahoofinance()` calls `db_data` to see if data for `ticker` is available in `db`

I have an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rO10X-0VtPfH1D5gPmxe8RFsxWkopLLT7k3_Cby_lfM/edit#gid=0).

```
function yahoofinance(ticker) {
  if (db_data(ticker)) {
    return get_db_data(ticker);
  }
  else {
    return get_live_data(ticker);
  }
}


function get_live_data(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [[fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}


function db_data(key) {
  var db =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db'); 
  var tickers = db.getDataRange('A2:A').getValues();

  for (var r = 0; r <= tickers.length; r++) { 
    if (tickers[r] == key) {
      return true // found a row with this key
    }
    else {
      return false // no row with this key exists
    }
  }
}
```

Issue: `db_data()` does not find ticker `AAPL` (see sheet `Dashboard`) even though it is present in sheet `db` so the matching in `db_data()` does not work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In the example you are using [`getDataRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) instead of [`getRange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation). Try to modify this line first.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I now use `var tickers = db.getRange('A2:A').getValues();` but that seems to result in an `#Error` (without details) in the cells where I'm calling `yahoofinance()`

Comment: If you move your mouse over the cell, what is the error message?

Comment: I just tested and it is  working for me, just one more change: `return get_db_data(ticker);` to `return db_data(ticker);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A working version of the script with the changes suggested in the comments:

```js
function yahoofinance(ticker) {
  if (db_data(ticker)) {
    return db_data(ticker);
  }
  else {
    return get_live_data(ticker);
  }
}


function get_live_data(ticker) {
  const url = 'https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/' + encodeURI(ticker) + '?modules=price,assetProfile,summaryDetail';
  
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true });
  if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
      var object = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  }

  let fwdPE  = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.summaryDetail?.forwardPE?.fmt || '-';
  let sector = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.assetProfile?.sector || '-';
  let mktCap = object.quoteSummary.result[0]?.price?.marketCap?.fmt || '-';

  return [[fwdPE, sector, mktCap]];
}


function db_data(key) {
  var db =  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('db'); 
  var tickers = db.getRange('A2:A').getValues();

  for (var r = 0; r <= tickers.length; r++) { 
    if (tickers[r] == key) {
      return true // found a row with this key
    }
    else {
      return false // no row with this key exists
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

[image: Results]

Comment: Thanks! Much appreciated. I have to build a lot more functionality in, but I hope this working basis will make next iterations easier bc I have sth to go with now :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!